# Do silicea capsules make hair thicker?

Tags: natural-remedies, hair

I had Silicea capsules suggested by a pharmacist as a food supplement which is supposed to help maintain healthy hair. The product is manufactured by hübner, entitled *Original Silicea Capsules*, the description says:

> - thicker hair
> - firmer skin
> - stronger nails
>
> Silica, a natural elemental substance derived from quartz crystals, is everywhere in nature where strength, elasticity and flexibility are important. It is an essential trace element for all living beings, and is found in each cell of your body. Silica is important for thick and vigorous hair, beautiful and firm skin, and strong nails. After the age of 20, the body loses its ability to store silica. The human body cannot produce silica itself and it has to be supplemented through diet.

Is there evidence that silica actually makes hair thicker?